# Reassign Chrome OS keybindings

Tags: key-bindings, google-chrome-os

I'm using Debian installed within a `chroot` via Crouton, on a Chromebook (OS Version 56.0.2924.110). There are keybindings I need for programs on like Alpine that are also in use by Chrome OS — mostly keybindings involving the CTRL key. The Chrome OS keybindings are numerous — those for CTRL-SHIFT, for instance, are shown in the attached screenshot.

Is there a way to reassign some of these Chrome OS keybindings so that I can use them freely within Debian?

[image: Chromebook control-key assignments]

Comment: I unfortunately have no idea about your question.  But, how did you make that image?  Did you do it manually, or did you find something that allows you to make a keybindings image?

Comment: It was a screenshot, @user1902689. 19 months on, I still have no idea about how to answer the question.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that you are using Debian within a "xiwi" window? In that case, the "keyboard" target of crouton may help.

Comment: I need to assign a Fn key to ctrl key. The Fn key is (quite annoying) located on the right side of the spacebar of my external keyboard. Any idea if that is possible?